# Import Csv File contents into MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, import

"q:how are you?","a:fine, How are you?"

My csv file is in this format.

How can I import it to csv

```
MariaDB [test]> LOAD DATA INFILE "D:/data.txt"    -> INTO TABLE DATA    -> COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','    -> ENCLOSED BY '"'    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'; Query OK, 34 rows affected, 67 warnings (0.01 sec) Records: 34  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 67
```

I've tried the above and I've 100 rows but it only stores 34.

Comment: There is something wrong with your csv file. There are 67 warnings. Take a closer look at the contents of file. Maybe, there are some issues with formatting in 67 remaining rows.

Comment: ok ill take a look @VitaliyG